# SMO - PropertyNotSetException when accessing table properties

Tags: c#, smo

I'm not sure if this is intended behaviour since I can't find it documented anywhere on MSDN, but this still seems a little bit odd.

I'm writing a program that makes use of SMO. For the sake of testing. I've basically got a test database, with a table in it (the structure is unimportant) that has the following trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTableInsert] ON [dbo].[MyTable] AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT 'after insert';
END
```

Now in my code. I expected to use this code to see (and prove) that the table 'MyTable' has an INSERT trigger. However running that code throws a `PropertyNotSetException`.

```
var table = new Table(database, tableName.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(table.HasInsertTrigger); // Throws PropertyNotSetException
```

But if I call the `Refresh()` method after initialising the table. The call to `HasInsertTrigger` returns true as excepted.

```
var table = new Table(database, tableName.ToString());
table.Refresh();
Console.WriteLine(table.HasInsertTrigger); // Returns true.
```

Making the call to `Refresh` seems unnecessary, but is it required as I can't find any documentation that says it needs to be called before accessing any properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have seen this a mile off... I was creating new instances of the tables rather than accessing existing ones.